# TextBox - Issue with validation using IDataErrorInfo with integer Value more than int.MaxValue (2147483647)

Tags: wpf, validation

In my WPF text box i have bound the integer entity variable and set the **IntegerValidationAttribute**.
when i input text **IDataErrorInfo**  is triggered with proper error info.

The issue is when i input the integer value more then int.MaxValue(2147483647) say i input 
**2147483649** the  **IDataErrorInfo** error is not triggered.

I need to disable/Enable button depends on proper integer value validation.

Please suggest for the same.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Is `IntegerValidationAttribute` custom? Have you tried the `RangeAttribute`?

Comment: Yes, IntegerValidationAttribute  is custom i have written.

Comment: your IDataErrorInfo is not triggered, because a BindingException is thrown, check your output window.

Comment: @user698209: Have you tried adding `ValidatesOnExceptions=True` to the Binding? As blindmeis points out, the conversion performed by the type descriptor is failing, raising an exception.

Comment: can you post your xaml binding, the integer property and the IDataErrorInfo and IntegerValidationAttribute

Answer (score 0):

when you put somthing like "cclks" in your textbox, your validation will also not happen or?

if not then you have some sort of "numeric only textbox" and if you have such a textbox you can go further and create a "integer numeric only textbox"

i always use string properties in my viewmodels so i can easily validate all input, but of course i have to cast to the real type for my models

Comment: Yes, i used **IntegerValidationAttribute**  and this is custom i have written. 
I used the  **RangeAttribute** also with max value set to 2147483647. When i input the 2147483648 then IDataErrorInfo is not triggered.  
I want to disable button when input exceeds **int.MaxValue**.  

Please let me know for any help.

Comment: look at your output window you should see a bindingexception. thats why there is no validation, even more your setter get not hit. its simply not possible to validate a int property wich is bind in xaml when you enter something wich its not an int ;) look at my answer i use string properties instead of int because i can validate them easy.

Comment: when i  input text or "cclks" validation will happen. only if the value exceeds int.MaxValue say 9999999999 then it is not triggering IDataErrorInfo , because of this i can't enable the button.

Comment: yes, i know well when we use string validation is very easy. Now i am using int database also int that is issue.   I am looking for solution for this issue currently.

Comment: i wonder why "cclks" input trigger your IDataErrorInfo? can you check your output window when you type 99999999999 and post the bindingexception.

Comment: i checked noting display on the output window.

Comment: well then you should post your code xaml binding, the integer property and the IDataErrorInfo and IntegerValidationAttribute

Comment: Hi all, Any solution for this issue.